# Code runs fine in SQL Server, but fails at the time of deploying

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please tell me as soon as possible?

```
create table aboutus_table 
(
    id int primary key identity(1,1),
    content char(7500),
)

select * from aboutus_table

create procedure admin_aboutus_save
(@aboutus_content char(7500))
as begin
   insert into aboutus_table(content)
   values(@aboutus_content)
end

create procedure admin_aboutus_detail
as begin
   select * from aboutus_table
end

create procedure admin_aboutus_detail_delete
(@aboutus_id int)
as begin
    delete aboutus_table where id=@aboutus_id 
end

create procedure admin_aboutus_detail_edit
(@aboutus_id int)
as begin
select * from aboutus_table where id=@aboutus_id
end

create procedure admin_aboutus_edited_save
(@aboutus_id int,
 @aboutus_content char(7500))
as begin
   update aboutus_table
   set content = @aboutus_content
   where id = @aboutus_id
end
```

This is my code. It is running fine in SQL Server, but at the time of deploying a website, when it am running above code in SQL Server, it is show error.

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'procedure'.
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@aboutus_id".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@aboutus_id".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@aboutus_id".

Comment: Asking the same question repeatedly does not help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601239/error-when-deploying-website-on-server-on-sql-server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601842/sql-server-error-when-deploying-on-sql-server-web-server. Specially after being give the solution 3 times, and still asking.

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, `CREATE PROCEDURE` must be the first statement in a query batch.

To force a piece of SQL to run in a new query batch, either execute that code separately, or place `GO` before it in SSMS.

Comment: can u give me an example where to put Go and what is SSMS.

Comment: SSMS stands for SQL Server Management Studio.  How are you executing your SQL.

Comment: thanks ....i ws not knowing the abbriviation. Can u please give me example for inserting a go command.

Comment: create table aboutus_table 
(
    id int primary key identity(1,1),
    content char(7500),
)
GO
select * from aboutus_table
GO

create procedure admin_aboutus_save
(@aboutus_content char(7500))
as begin
insert into aboutus_table
(
    content
)
values
(   
    @aboutus_content 
)
end
GO.............is it correct auur i have to use semicolon also....